Unable to add github account in smartgit on mac via Personal Access Token
I have been trying to add github account in smartgit (23.1.3) and its constantly failing with same error.
I have tried automatic token generation as well as manual login using a Personal Access token, but to no good. I did try dabbling into the low level properties but could not figure out what to change to get it working.

Any help in this regards would be really great. This is specific to Github only as i was able to add gitlab accounts easily.
